# Google script do not run in iPadOS 15

Tags: google-apps-script, ipad

I'm a neophyte here and I would appreciate if anyone could put some light on my problem.   I have a project  I've developed using Google Sheet and I use it in my iMac. When I open the same Google Sheet (in my Google Drive) in my iPad Pro, running iPadOS 15, the system do not offer me the opportunity to open my App Acript Project. Any help?

Comment: On iPad, are you opening the Google sheet in the browser (Safari/Firefox/Chrome etc) or on the app ?

Comment: Hi, I tried to  open my Google Sheet (with app script macros) from Google Sheet App and Google Drive App. In Both cases , the macros didn't work.

Comment: Script support in Mobile App is limited.  Many users attempt to improve that my using onedit to call functions.  Personally, I'd rather use the desktop.

Comment: Hi, Cooper. I am forced to agree with you. The problem is that I feel deceived by Apple who, in the advertisement for the iPad Pro, said that it would replace the desktop. I see now that it was a fake new. Thank you for comment

Answer (score 0):

Google mobile apps like Google Sheets app don't include a menu option to create / open a bounded script editor. Also the Class UI doesn't work in mobile apps i.e. a custom menu will not be shown but and edit and change triggers might work. If you need the full functionality of Google Apps Script open your spreadsheet using a web browser in desktop mode.

P.S. If you want to go "directly" to your script you might use the Google Apps Script project URL or open you can find it in https://script.google.com.

Comment: Thank you, for your comment.  I did what you proposed and I had access to the macros I developed in my iMac, but I still can not execute the macros through my Google Sheet in my iPad Pro. rephrasing my question: can I run my Google Sheet (with its Google-proclaimed automation macros) on iPad OS? Thanks again for your attention.rephrasing my question: can I run my Google Sheet (with its Google-proclaimed automation macros) on iPad OS?  From your comment, I understood that not, since Google mobile app do not allow  to open a bounded script. Is that correct?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the necessary clarifications an to show what you have tried including the name and version of the web browser used. Tip try using a desktop browser.

Answer (score 0):

I've able to run all the scripts I've wanted to by triggering them from the onEdit() function.

Use data validation to create a drop-down, then have the onEdit() code check that the edit is in the relevant cell, then run a function chosen according to the new cell value.